# Как прочитать данные с сетевого диска либо по локальному пути MVC

Tags: c#, windows, asp.net-mvc, iis

Пишу маленький проект с подключением файла с сетевого диска, при публикации на локальном ПК получаю исключение

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Не удалось найти часть пути

затем я решил в поле пути прописать явное подключение

```
string path = "\\\\192.168.0.2\\delete\\test.dat
```

и снова получаю исключение:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Отказано в доступе по пути
>   \192.168.0.2\delete\test.dat

И как бы ясно что система требует логин пароль, я на MSDN нашел вот такой пример: 
в `web.config` добавляем :

```
  <configuration>
   <system.web>
      <identity impersonate="true" userName="192.168.0.2\Admin"
          password="pass123"//>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

И всеравно получаю ошибку, в которой сказано что такого пользователя и пароля не существует в системе, помогите пожалуйста решить проблему. Спасибо

Comment: попробуйте дать доступ к папке: как [советуют тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21498502/3373603)

Comment: @Ruslan_K Не получилось

Comment: Для начала признайтесь, у вас веб-приложение или декстопное? Или вообще вин-сервис?

Comment: @PavelMayorov стоит же тег `MVC`

Comment: @tCode этот тэг тут вообще непонятно зачем, потому что означает общий паттерн проектирования.

Comment: @tCode есть у меня, конечно, подозрение что имелось в виду asp.net mvc - но нужно подтверждение от автора

Answer (score 5):

Источник: [en SO: How to provide user name and password when connecting to a network share](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1197430/4340086)

Попробуйте так, у меня работает

### NetworkManager

```
public class NetworkManager : IDisposable
{
    private readonly string _networkName;

    public NetworkManager(string networkName)
    {
        _networkName = networkName;

        NetResource netResource = new NetResource
        {
            Scope = ResourceScope.GlobalNetwork,
            ResourceType = ResourceType.Any,
            DisplayType = ResourceDisplayType.Directory,
            RemoteName = networkName
        };

        int result = WNetAddConnection2(netResource, "ВАШ ПАРОЛЬ", "ВАШ ЛОГИН", 0);

        if (result != 0)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(result);
        }
    }

    ~NetworkManager()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        WNetCancelConnection2(_networkName, 0, true);
    }

    [DllImport("mpr.dll")]
    private static extern int WNetAddConnection2(NetResource netResource, string password, string username, int flags);

    [DllImport("mpr.dll")]
    private static extern int WNetCancelConnection2(string name, int flags, bool force);
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class NetResource
{
    public ResourceScope Scope;
    public ResourceType ResourceType;
    public ResourceDisplayType DisplayType;
    public int Usage;
    public string LocalName;
    public string RemoteName;
    public string Comment;
    public string Provider;
}

public enum ResourceScope
{
    Connected = 1,
    GlobalNetwork,
    Remembered,
    Recent,
    Context
}

public enum ResourceType
{
    Any = 0,
    Disk = 1,
    Print = 2,
    Reserved = 8,
}

public enum ResourceDisplayType
{
    Generic = 0x0,
    Domain = 0x01,
    Server = 0x02,
    Share = 0x03,
    File = 0x04,
    Group = 0x05,
    Network = 0x06,
    Root = 0x07,
    Shareadmin = 0x08,
    Directory = 0x09,
    Tree = 0x0a,
    Ndscontainer = 0x0b
}
```

### Использование

```
using (NetworkManager network = new NetworkManager(@"\\192.168.0.2"))
{
    // ваш код с подключением
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57817/discussion-on-answer-by-tcode---------).